# Blender - Vector Field Animation

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, force-fields, vector-mapping, vector

I am trying to create an animation of a vector field for my university Physics project. I ideally would like to create something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcQuqxYU-UY so with moving arrows / vectors and possibly also smoke. I have been experimenting with Blender for a few weeks but I am still unsure how to start, or even if this is possible in Blender. Any advice or guidance on how I can create this sort of animation would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I dindt find a way to get motion vectors from smoke sim. But if you had them you could do the arrow-part with the add-on animation nodes. Maby Houdini is also a good look for your goal or a combination of both.

Comment: Thats great, thank you I will have a look at animation nodes